# What is an example of an accessor method?

Tags: accessor

I got this question from a worksheet my AP Computer Science teacher had on his worksheet:

```
class Exam{
private int myA, myB;
private final int MAX = 100;

public Exam( ) { myA = myB = 100; }
public Exam ( int a, int b ) {   myA = a; myB = b; }

public void setA(int a) { myA = a; }
public void setB(int b) { myB = b; }

public int getA() { return myA; }
public int getB() { return myB; }

public String toString( ) { return getA() + " " + getB(); }
}
```

How many accessor methods are in Exam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three are accessor methods.  An accessor "accesses" the variable.  Only three of them directly return the `private` variables.  All of the others are mutators because they "mutate" the variables.  The last accessor listed below is not a great accessor because it doesn't follow encapsulation best practices.

These are the accessors.

```
 public int getA() { return myA; }
 public int getB() { return myB; }
 public String toString( ) { return getA() + " " + getB(); }
```

Comment: I guess you could call the last one an accessor because it is accessing the variables.  Generally, this wouldn't be best practice for encapsulation.

Comment: How exactly does toString() break encapsulation?

Comment: toString() is public and encapsulation is when methods have private access.

Comment: It doesn't break encapsulation.  I just don't think it is great practice to have a return statement like that.